# Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse - error Python

Tags: python, datetime, regression, var, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to do a VAR on some sentiment values and return numbers.

```
tr = pd.read_csv("PATH", skiprows = 0 ,index_col = 1,squeeze = True, sep = ";", decimal=",")

tr.index = pd.to_datetime(tr.index, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
tr = tr.reset_index()
tr["quarter"] = tr["quarter"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
tr.set_index('quarter', inplace=True)
tr.index = pd.to_datetime(tr.index, format = "%Y-%m")
```

I am loading the return Data like this (parse_dates did somehow not work properly when reading the data). I had to do the code below the "read_csv" as it would give me an error when using as.freq in order to plot the values -> works now.

Even though I used `tr.index = pd.to_datetime(tr.index, format = "%Y-%m")` my data looks like:

```
quarter                    total return
2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z   0.09
```

I am reading the sentiment values like this:

```
Index = pd.read_csv("PATH", parse_dates = [0], index_col = 0, skiprows = 0 ,squeeze = True, sep = ";", decimal=",")
```

Dataframe structure is the previous one with the same format for dates.

Here I somehow had not to change anything and it would plot the data without a problem.

The quarter column is set as a `DateTimeIndex`

I set both as frequency for plotting.

```
tr = tr.asfreq(pd.infer_freq(tr.index)) 
Index = Index.asfreq(pd.infer_freq(Index.index))
```

When I try to run a test for lagged dependency:

```
for lag in range (1, 24):
    tr = tr["return"].iloc[lag:]
    lagged_opt = Index["Sentiment"].iloc[:-lag]
    print("lag: %s"%lag)
    print(pearsonr(tr, lagged_opt))
    print("-------")
```

I get this error : `Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: tr`

Does anyone have an idea whats the problem here?

Comment: `2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` is pretty standard, see [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). You can parse like `pd.to_datetime(["2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"])` for example, without providing a `format`.

Comment: I did apply `tr.index = pd.to_datetime(tr.index)`. Then the entries in the column are like `pd.to_datetime(["2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"])`. Everything works until I want to run the lagged dependencies test with the code above. Only here I get the error `Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: tr'

Comment: Is that the full error traceback? Which line is throwing it? Is it the call to `pearsonr`? From which package do you import that function?

Comment: It says there has another error occured while handling the above one stating `DateParseError` then some file directory and at the end : `KeyError: 'tr'`. The `pearsonr` comes from: `from scipy.stats import pearsonr`.

Comment: I found the mistake: The "total return" values needed to be changed to "numeric" as it somehow had problems with negative values. Now everything works! Thanks for your input nonetheless!